# Can two different pronouns (that, who) be used to refer to the same antecedent (a statue representing a person)?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, antecedents

"He is being crowned by a female figure **that** accompanies him and **who** represents Victory."

The figure itself is, of course, not a human, but its representation is (or at least is anthropomorphic). I would accept either/or, but having both "that" and "who" referring to "figure" gives me a headache.

Comment: Certainly I agree, but I am an editor and I want to adhere as closely as possible to the author's voice.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the OP's question:

Yes, it is fine to use different pronouns to refer to the same antecedent.

In the OP's example, the antecedent refers not to a statue but to a female figure in a statue. So the appropriate pronouns are "that" and "who". If the antecent referred to the statue itself, the appropriate pronouns are "that" and "which". For example, the statue **that** the OP mentioned, **which** was sculpted by XXX, depicts YYY being crowned by a female figure representing Victory.

Answer (score 0):

A sentence can be strictly 'correct' but jar on the ear.  This can be done for a literary effect.  "She walked through the snow wrapped in thought  and a charming Burberry overcoat."  is an example.  It is meant to sound funny.  It juxtaposes a metaphorical and literal use of the same verb.  I am sure you know that this device is called 'zeugma' (from the Greek word for 'to join').  To edit that would interfere with the author's literary 'voice'.

The sentence in question certainly jars on the ear.  But I can see nothing about the usage mentioned here that has to do with authorial voice.  The demonstrative pronoun, *that*, which in the US has a well establish usage as a relative pronoun, replacing the relative pronoun, *which* in contexts like the  one in your quotation, is becoming more common in British English.

However, the use of *who* is itself strange.  A statue is inanimate.  **It** represents an animate divinity, Victory.  But the "female figure" is not Victory herself, but the inanimate representation of her.  So it is wrong to use the personal pronoun in this context, because it refers to the inanimate representation.

There is no easy way out of this merging of the representation and represented.  You might consider:

> He is accompanied by the female figure of Victory, who is crowning <or, who crowns> him.

The idea of authorial voice in what seems to be about a painting, whether as part of a book or of a museum guide, is not obviously appropriate.  An alternative wording, whether my suggestion or just the omission of 'who', makes no difference to the authorial voice.